# Apache Camel: route using custom processor, splitter and aggregator doesn't output anything

Tags: apache-camel

I'm cutting my teeth on Camel using the following use case:

> Given a GitHub username, I want to fetch a certain number of public
>   repos in descending order of activity, then for each repo I want to
>   fetch a certain number of commits, and finally, for each commit, I
>   want to print some information.

To achieve this, I wrote a `Producer` and the following route. The Producer works (I've tests), and so does the route without the aggregator. When using the aggregator, nothing comes out (my tests fail).

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("direct:start")
            .id("gitHubRoute")
            .filter(and(
                    isNotNull(simple("${header." + ENDPOINT + "}")),
                    isNotNull(simple("${body}")))
            )
            .setHeader(USERNAME, simple("${body}"))
            .toD("github:repos?username=${body}")
            .process(e -> {
                // some processing
            })
            .split(body())
            .parallelProcessing()
            .setHeader(REPO, simple("${body.name}"))
            .toD("github:commits" +
                    "?repo=${body.name}" +
                    "&username=${header." + USERNAME + "}"
            )
            .process(e -> {
                // some processing
            })
            .split(body())
            .toD("github:commit" +
                    "?repo=${header." + REPO + "}" +
                    "&username=${header." + USERNAME + "}" +
                    "&sha=${body.sha}"
            )
            .process(e -> {
                // some processing
            })
            .aggregate(header(REPO), new GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy()).completionTimeout(10000l)
            .toD("${header." + ENDPOINT + "}");

    from("direct:end")
            .process().exchange(this::print);
}
```

During testing, I set the header `ENDPOINT` to `mock:result`. In reality, it's set to `direct:end`.

What am I doing wrong? There are no errors but the `print` method, or the mock during testing, is never invoked.

Comment: In my view this route is already too complicated for a test. Wouldn't it be better to break this into 2-3 smaller routes which make it easier to test each step and know where something is going worng?

Comment: Study how the aggregate works in more. I dont have time here to explain but for example the Camel website, books etc. In short the aggregator is two legged, so output of it runs independent on the input.

Comment: I assume the problem might be in a way you indicate aggregation completion. Try with completionInterval instead of completionTimeout. You can also use completionSize. There are a few other options available, for more info please refer to http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html "About completion" section.

Comment: @ClausIbsen "Study more" is not helpful. I did my homework, and it should be apparent in the question. My problem was completing the aggregation, and as you can see, I've found the solution myself. As for reading Camel website, it's most of the times a joke, although Aggregator is somewhat better than the others. But then, there are 2 Aggregator pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. Couple of things that I'd to change:

1. Completion check: I used a `completionPredicate` as shown below.
2. `eagerCheckCompletion()`: Without this, the exchange passed into the `completionPredicate` is the aggregated exchange, not the incoming exchange.

I also took the opportunity to do little refactoring to improve readability.

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("direct:start")
            .id("usersRoute")
            .filter(isNotNull(simple("${header." + ENDPOINT + "}")))
            .setHeader(USERNAME, simple("${body}"))
            .toD("github:users/${body}/repos")
            .process(e -> this.<GitHub.Repository>limitList(e))
            .to("direct:reposRoute1");

    from("direct:reposRoute1")
            .id("reposRoute1")
            .split(body())
            .parallelProcessing()
            .setHeader(REPO, simple("${body.name}"))
            .toD("github:repos/${header." + USERNAME + "}" + "/${body.name}/commits")
            .process(e -> this.<GitHub.Commit>limitList(e))
            .to("direct:reposRoute2");

    from("direct:reposRoute2")
            .id("reposRoute2")
            .split(body())
            .toD("github:repos/${header." + USERNAME + "}" + "/${header." + REPO + "}" + "/commits/${body.sha}")
            .process(e -> {
                GitHub.Commit commit = e.getIn().getBody(GitHub.Commit.class);

                List<GitHub.Commit.File> files = commit.getFiles();
                if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(files) && files.size() > LIMIT) {
                    commit.setFiles(files.subList(0, LIMIT));
                    e.getIn().setBody(commit);
                }
            })
            // http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html
            .aggregate(header(REPO), new AggregateByRepoStrategy())
            .forceCompletionOnStop()
            .eagerCheckCompletion()
            .completionPredicate(header("CamelSplitComplete").convertTo(Boolean.class).isEqualTo(TRUE))
            .toD("${header." + ENDPOINT + "}");

    from("direct:end")
            .process().exchange(this::print);
}
```

The `AggregationStrategy` I used as follows:

```
private static final class AggregateByRepoStrategy extends AbstractListAggregationStrategy<GitHub.Commit> {
    @Override
    public GitHub.Commit getValue(Exchange exchange) {
        return exchange.getIn().getBody(GitHub.Commit.class);
    }
}
```